# Determine an area coordinates

Tags: android

I have to determine an area with using QR codes. I have got 4 QR kod on the margin of carrying car. I want to scan the true division and paint with a color (e.g. yellow). We will find the true division with a list.For example; First we will paint 5 then 2 then 1 etc.But I don't know how can I start.
 I draw a sample picture,

[image: Sample Picture]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to know the number of pixels in the green area or its real-world size?

Comment: Please read about [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to edit your question. With high quality questions you will receive better answers faster. Thanks!

Comment: I gave a lot of detail about the problem.Thank you for suggestion @JanGreve